# Правила продвижения малых целых типов

Tags: c++, продвижение, int, promotions

Никак не могу найти информацию, которая бы детально описывала правила продвижения малых целых типов в `C++`.

Правила продвижения малых целых в рамках языка `C` мне хорошо известны. Если я правильно помню, у `C` и `C++` в этих правилах есть отличия. Подскажите, в чем они заключаются, а то поисковики, как на зло, направляют меня в обсуждения, касающиеся `C`, а не `C++`.

Comment: Проще всего взять да и посмотреть что получается (если сомнения остались, то почитать асм, который генерит компайлер), поскольку все описания  в стандартах такие, что в них проще запутаться, чем однозначно понять (а главное, запомнить), что и когда произойдет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я знаю только одно место, где это должно быть правильно описано - собственно стандарт языка. Глава называется [Integral promotions](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/conv.prom)